# Return true if the string in the first element of the array contains all of the letters of the string in the second element of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mutation

My code is running except for mutation([“Mary”, “Army”]) should return true, but it is returning false and
mutation([“Mary”, “Aarmy”]) should return true, but it is returning false.

Can someone please explain why this is happening?

My code so far

```js
function mutation(arr) {
    a=arr.slice(0,1); var a_str  = a.toString();  a_arr  =  Array.from(a_str);  
    b=arr.slice(1,2); var b_str  = b.toString();  b_arr  =  Array.from(b_str);
    var  flag=0; 

    for(var  i=0;i<b_arr.length;i++){  
        for(var  j=0;j<a_arr.length;j++){
            if(b_arr[i]==a_arr[j]){
                flag+=1;
            }
        }
    }

    if(flag>=b_arr.length){
        return  true;
    } else  return  false;
}

console.log(mutation(["Mary", "Aarmy"]));
```

Comment: Are you handling case-sensitivity (capitalization)? I.e. `"M"` isn't the same as `"m"`

Comment: javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: Yes, I tried and it worked thankyou so much for that. But now I am trying for mutation(["voodoo", "no"]); and it should return false but it is returning true.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem :

The problem with your code is that JavaScript is `case-sensitive` while your code doesn't expect that so here is what you can do :

## Solution :

if both are equal in that case :

then you can basically do anagram check :

```js
anagram = _ => _.toLowerCase().split('').sort().join('').trim();

const isAnagram = _ => anagram(_[0]) === anagram(_[1])
```

Other wise you can do something along these lines :

```js
check = a => !a[0].split ``.map(_ => _[X = `toLowerCase`]()).filter(_ => !a[1].includes(_[X]())).length

console.log(check(['Mary','Aarmy']))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this really simply if you use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). For example:

```js
const mutation = arr => {
  var a = new Set(arr[0].toLowerCase())
  var b = new Set(arr[1].toLowerCase())
  return [...a].every(ch => b.has(ch))  
}

console.log(mutation(["Mary", "Army"]))
console.log(mutation(["Mary", "Aarmy"]))
console.log(mutation(["Mary", "Aary"]))
console.log(mutation(["ab", "abba"]))
console.log(mutation(["voodoo", "no"]))
```

I still feel like there is some ambiguity in the question, but if exactness was required, you could also just check that the set sizes were equal (as they contain all unique letters)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map`, `filter` and `toLowerCase` functions to achieve this.

**Example:**

```js
function mutation(arr){ 
    return !arr[0].split("")
    .map(x => x.toLowerCase())
    .filter(l => !arr[1].includes(l.toLowerCase())).length
}

var res = mutation(["Mary", "Aarmy"]);

console.log(res); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `toLowerCase()` to compare each character with case insensitivity. And you can further remove the extra inner loop and do something like this:

```js
function mutation(checkArray){
  var firstElement = checkArray[0];
  var secondElement = checkArray[1];
  var splitSecondElement = secondElement.split('');
  var matched = true;
  for(var i=0; i<splitSecondElement.length; i++){
    var firstElementLower = firstElement.toLowerCase();
    var characterLower = splitSecondElement[i].toLowerCase();
    if(firstElementLower.indexOf(characterLower) === -1){
      matched = false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return matched;
}

console.log(mutation(["Mary", "Army"]));
console.log(mutation(["Mary", "Aarmy"]));
console.log(mutation(["Mary", "Aarmyxyz"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var yes;
function mutation(arr){
arr[1]=arr[1].toLowerCase();
arr[0]=arr[0].toLowerCase();

for (var i=0; i<a[1].length; i++){
    if(!(arr[0].includes(arr[1].charAt(i))){
    return yes= false;
    }
    else{
         yes= true;
          }
   }
   console.log(yes);
  }
  mutation(["hello","hey"]);
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does.

Comment: This is a free code camp problem and my code works. So if the characters in the second array can be found in the first array it will return true otherwise it will return false. The if statement I wrote simply means that if the first array which is arr[0] does not include even a single character in the second array return false.  In here, hey is the second array and we are looping through all the characters with charAt(i) and all chars need to exist inside the first array. The var yes is a boolean that gets overwritten to false as soon as there is one character mismatch